# Counting the instances of an object in an image with OpenCV2

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to write a program in Python that detects how many times an object appears in an image. I have a template picture of a marker and a larger picture with 4 markers in different rotations. Here are the images I'm using:
Template: https://ibb.co/r7rLnRr
Larger image: https://ibb.co/B6TCkRY

I've tried feature matching but that just matches parts of an object and because of that it says there are way more instances than there really are. I've also tried template matching, which I still feel like is my best choice but it doesn't react well to changes in object size and rotation. Do you have any suggestions? Maybe how can I adapt template matching to account for changes in size/rotation?

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you searched Google?  For example see https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/ and https://github.com/DennisLiu1993/Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Turn your image of color markers into grayscale.

Use [Hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)
on that to find lines.

Your grayscale template image is smaller,
so we will prefer it for manipulations.

Using angles detected by Hough,
create rotated copies of the template,
and match each one to the target image.
You may find it helpful to do bbox detection
so you can scale the template to the proper size.